# Neural net fails to generalize a simple bitwise AND

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

After taking bunch of online courses and reading many papers I started playing with neural-net but to my surprise it fails to generalize a simple bitwise AND operation.

Inputs:

```
Inp#1 - randomly generated number between 0-15, scaled down to (0,1)
Inp#2 - 16 bit randomly generated unsigned int scaled down to (0,1)

# Code snippet
int in1 = (int)rand()%16;
int in2 = (int)rand()%(0x0010000);
in[0] = (fann_type)(in1/100.0);    // not to worry about float roundup
in[1] = (fann_type)(in2/100000.0); // not to worry about float roundup
```

Outputs:

```
Out#1 = -1 if the corresponding bit specified by index inp#1 in inp#2 value is 0, otherwise 1

# Code snippet
int out1 = (in2 & (1<<in1)) ? 1 : -1;
out[0] = (fann_type)out1;
```

Network: tried many different variations, below is example

```
A. 1 hidden layer with 30 neurons, 
    Activation Function (hidden): sigmoid,
    Activation Function (output): sigmoid_symmetric (tanh),
    Training method: RPROP
    Learning rate: 0.7 (default)
    Momentum: 0.0 (default)
    RPROP Increase factor: 1.2 (default)
    RPROP Decrease factor: 0.5 (default)
    RPROP Minimum Step-size: 0 (default)
    RPROP Maximum Step-size: 50 (default)


B. 3 hidden layers each having 30 neurons, with the same params as in A

C. tried the same networks also with scaling inputs to (-1,1) and using tanh for also hidden layer.
```

Data Sets: 5000 samples for training, 5000 for testing and 5000 for validation. Tried even bigger datasets, no success

```
# examples from training set
0.040000 0.321600 
-1 
0.140000 0.625890 
1 
0.140000 0.039210 
-1 
0.010000 0.432830 
1 
0.100000 0.102220 
1
```

Process: the network trained with training set and monitored the MSE of test data in parallel to avoid possible overfitting.

Libraries: used multiple, but mostly tried with fann and used fanntool for gui.

Any ideas? Can upload the datasets if any particular interest.

Comment: What's your learning rate? What are the values of the cost function during the training process?

Comment: Updated the description to cover the missing information and also provided actual code snippets. Thanks

Comment: What are you doing is a classification task. Why are you using -1, 1 outputs and MSE instead 0, 1 and log-loss? It is proved that such setup is doing better job. Btw. this task is not easy. It looks pretty harsh for neural net to learn such operation.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback Marcin. The reason i am doing regression is that this is in fact oversimplified version of what i started with (inp1 & inp2 = out, where all are 16bit). I am just surprised that 30 neurons with sigmoid activation cannot generalize *at all* the bitwise AND. The MSE does not even go down a bit for testing set. Is this really expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your setup, you try to do something like:

- have a network of architecture 2-X-X-X-1 (where X - hidden units) - thus 2 inputs, one output
- model **bitwise** function over inputs

If this is true, this is **extremely peculiar problem**, and a very bad choice of architecture. Neural networks are not magical hats, they are very big family of models. What you try to do has **no** characteristics, which is expected from function to model by NN. It is completely non smooth in the input, it has lots of discontinuities, it is actually a bunch of if-else clauses.

What you should do? You should express your inputs **as bits**, thus you should have 32 inputs, 16 binary inputs per number, then it will learn your function without any problems. You encoded inputs in a very specific manner (by taking its decimal representation) and expect your network to model decomposition to binary and then operation on top of it. NN will learn it, but you might need quite complex network to achieve such operation - again, the whole reason is the fact that you provided your network with suboptimal representation and build a very simple network, which was originally designed to approximate smooth functions.

Comment: Thanks for feedback. I agree, however the reason for experimenting this way was to see if neural net can derive that more optimal representation by using first/second hidden layers all by itself instead of me adapting manually to my given specific problem. I hoped hand-picking features is exectly what deep nets try to replace

Comment: Your Network is not Deep. As I said you will solved it with current setting but you need more capacity    as function that you are trying to model is not cpmaptible with the model of computations. Linear combinations of sigmoids are not good to representation if clauses. Furthermore represenring data as bias os not feature engineering

Comment: Dl assuming that you give a RAW input,  in Rich input space. You provide your data in highly compressed manner. 2d input is hard for nns if the function is not reaaalllly smooth